fcm flutter how to check if user viewed notification
i want to check if user viewed notification in background or terminated.
if user viewed, show empty container.
if user didn't view, show like this.

I am using the getx controller variable with a bool value.
And update the screen according to the variable.
This is home.dart. It shows read or unread mark.

// Controller to check read or unread
class UnreadNotiController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isUnread = false.obs;
}

Widget menuBox(screenSize) {
  final unreadNotiController = Get.put(UnreadNotiController());

  return Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(...),
        Stack(
          children: [
            Row(... ),
            // Show read or unread mark
            Obx(() => Positioned(
              left: screenSize.width / 2 - 75,
              child: unreadNotiController.isUnread.value
              ? Container(
                width: 20, 
                height: 20, 
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red, 
                  shape: BoxShape.circle, 
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.white, 
                    width: 2, 
                  ),
                )
              ) 
              : Container()
            )
            ) 
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

This is backgroundHandler

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

  // When receiving a message in background or terminated, 
  // change the value to an unread message.
  final unreadNotiController = Get.put(UnreadNotiController());
  unreadNotiController.isUnread.value = true;

  // Android channel
  const channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(...);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(...);


  showNotification(message);
}

Other than setting this notification badge, all notifications work perfectly.
terminated to foreground -> UI is updated normally.
background to foreground -> UI isn't updated normally.
I think the screen updates normally when the app is completely restarted, but it doesn't update otherwise. If you have any good opinions, please help
